# Data Manipulation in R Project: compare rows

Tags: r

I'm looking to compare values within a dataset

Every row starts with a unique ID followed by a couple binary variables
The data looks like this:

```
row.name v1 v2 v3 ... 
1         0  0  0
2         1  1  1
3         1  0  1
```

I want to know which values are the same (if equal assign value of 1) and which are different (if not equal assign value of 0) for all unique pairings.
For example in column v1: row1 == 0 and row2 == 1, which should result in an assignment of 0.

So, the output should look like this

```
id1 id2 v1 v2 v3 ...
  1   2  0  0  0 ...
  1   3  0  1  0 ...
  2   3  1  0  1 ...
```

I'm looking for an efficient way of doing this for more than 1000 rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this without expanding each combination of rows, so with 1000 rows, it is going to take a bit of time.  But here is a solution:

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text="row.name v1 v2 v3 
1         0  0  0
2         1  1  1
3         1  0  1")
```

Create the index rows:

```
indices <- t(combn(dat$row.name, 2))
colnames(indices) <- c('id1', 'id2')
```

Loop through the index rows, and collect the comparisons:

```
res1 <- t(apply(indices, 1, function(x) as.numeric(dat[x[1],-1] == dat[x[2],-1])))
colnames(res1) <- names(dat[-1])
```

Put them together:

```
result <- cbind(indices, res1)

result
##      id1 id2 v1 v2 v3
## [1,]   1   2  0  0  0
## [2,]   1   3  0  1  0
## [3,]   2   3  1  0  1
```

Comment: That worked like a charm (took some CPU time though).
Thank you